# Protecting ADC pin from the opamp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, circuit-protection

i am working on a design circuit and i have to measure the current going through the loads so i put shunt resistor 0.1ohms and from the terminals of that resistor to an instrumental opamp, then to ADC pin in microcontroller, my question is can i put a mosfet transistor and switch on/off the opamp supply voltage when i don't want it to protect the ADC pin of the microcontroller (is it of to the opamp or its going to be broken?)or can i put a zener diode?

i want to protect the ADC pin from the un expected voltages, i am suppling the circuit by 12v and the microcontrollers is 5v max
thanks in advance, and feel free to say your opinion or any advice [image]

updated graph  [image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. The OP's circuit.*

Here are a few comments:

1. This looks suspiciously like an LM317 regulator in current control mode. That means your output voltage could swing from 0 (in a short-circuit) to about 9 V. You are showing a variable resistor in there which suggests that you are thinking of making it adjustable. I suggest you calculate the current you are going to run through this and then start to look at the current rating of typical potentiometers. Remember that the power rating for a pot assumes dissipation over the full length of the resistance track. If you have it set to mid-position then the power rating is halved. (i.e., work out the maximum current the pot will handle.)
2. You have several parallel loads. Since these are driven by one constant-current source you won't be able to control the current in each branch. Your shunts are on the "high side" of the loads and so could see up to 9 V on them.
3. This is OK and will switch off all loads.
4. Your multiplexer will have to cope with the 9 V on the shunts. You have no supply voltage indicated for this device so this may be the first to blow.
5. Your op-amp has no gain control and no offset adjustment to remove the high-side voltage.

It would help if you edit your question to explain what exactly you are trying to make and why.

Low-side current monitoring simplifies everything as the multiplexer and op-amp can be powered from the 5 V microcontroller supply.

What is the purpose of the MOSFET (3)?

Comment: OK, but do it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: hello sir, thanks for you clear explanation, i will answer all the points with the same order like you asked 1) i forgot to put the name of the components so the regulator is LM317, i used it to control the voltage and the current for the load branch to obtain a voltage drop over the load only around 6-6.5v max 2) yes sir i put the shunt resistor on the high side for mor stability in measuring the voltage drop around it according to an article 3)the mosfet is going to be used for PWM controlling 4)the supply of the multiplexer is 12v 5) the gain of the opamp is 500

Comment: the article of the high side shunt resistor https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/whitepaper/21123363/5-currentsensing-resistors

Comment: my question is how to protect the ADC pin from the unexpected voltages from the output of the opamp, and the output of the opamp is around 1.25-1.4v as i have tested on only one branch not nine but i am thinking about the worst case scenario, another question, is it ok to switch on/off the supply voltage of the opamp like a mosfet or its not designed for that purpose and it is going to be damaged?

Comment: Use a voltage divider or a voltage clamping circuit for ADC protection. Most devices won't like you to apply input voltages higher than supply so switching off the op-amp could be destructive.